# Can't set up Xamarin Forms Unit Test using MSTest with Prism

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, prism, mstest

I have a new Xamarin Forms (3.2) project using .NetStandard library (2.0.3) and Prism/Unity for navigation and dependency injection. I have been struggling to set up basic unit tests.

My unit test project has a single unit test class that is trying to test a method in a ViewModel class (LoginPageViewModel). The ViewModel class inherits from a ViewModelBase which inherits from Prism's BindableBase and implements Prism's INavigationAware interface.

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible
```

I have two constructors. The second I created just for the unit test because I don't need the INavigationService for the tests.

```
public LoginPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IdentityService identityService) : base(navigationService)

public LoginPageViewModel(IIdentityService identityService) : base()
```

The project builds, but I get this exception for each of my tests:

> Message: Test method
>   SalesOrderApp.UnitTests.LoginPageViewModelTests.UserLogin_LoginFails_ReturnsFalseAndNoToken
>   threw exception:  System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Prism.Navigation.INavigationAware' from assembly 'Prism,
>   Version=7.1.0.431, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40ee6c3a2184dc59'.

I have the same version of Prism.Unity.Forms (7.1.0.431) installed in the MSTest project as I have in the project that I am testing. I have been struggling to get the MSTests to work with Prism. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproduction I can only make assumptions here. Based on the exception it would appear that it cannot resolve the Navigation interfaces. This tells me that your unit test project is targeting the full .Net Framework (net45) which the only scenario that would cause that exception.

You can retarget your unit tests to either a device runner which I recommend if you’re using Xamarin, or simply netcore.

Comment: Thanks Dan. You are correct. I am testing my .Net Standard 2.0 project and my unit test project is targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2. I am trying to understand what you mean by retargeting the unit tests to a device runner. Can you point me to information on this?

Comment: @Steve probably the simplest thing is to simply retarget to `netcoreapp2.1`. A little more advanced though better because you can discover platform specific issues is to use a device runner, which is itself a Xamarin iOS/Android project that runs your tests. Since you said you're using MSTest, you'll want to check out [MSTestX](https://github.com/dotMorten/MSTestX) which is an OSS port to run MSTest projects directly on iOS/Android.

Answer (score 0):

To make things a bit more clear for future readers:

Ran into the same issue not being able to resolve Prism's `INavigationService` using MSTest. To fix this I had to manually edit our unit test's `.csproj` to point to .NETStandard

**BEFORE:**

```xml
<HintPath>..\packages\Prism.Core.7.1.0.431\lib\net45\Prism.dll</HintPath>
```

**AFTER**

```xml
<HintPath>..\packages\Prism.Core.7.1.0.431\lib\netstandard2.0\Prism.dll</HintPath>
```

Presto changeo! Fixed up